# #1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server after acunetix scan

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am using the xampp .
As stated in the question i am getting the #1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server after i ran acunetix vulnerability scan on my localhost .

I researched and found some solutions but on running the first command of the solutions i.e
 `mysql -u root --host=127.0.0.1 -p=` , i get the same error.

Please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449071/1130-host-localhost-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server-after http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513888/phpmyadmin-wont-stop-throwing-1130-host-localhost-is-not-allowed-to-conne Doesn't look like there are any good solutions. I would wipe it, reinstall MySQL and restore the data from backups.

Comment: @Ladadadada actually i dont have the backup of database of yesterday. Thats why i was looking for the solution. Seems like i'll have to go as you suggest , thanks any way.But still waiting for some one to give the solution coz i'll be regularly using acunetix.  This problem will be a daily affair